# How do I use XmlAttribute value to determine where to store XmlElement value?

Tags: java, xml, annotations

My XML file looks like this:

```
<root>
    <element attribute="valueA">one</element>
    <element attribute="valueB">two</element>
    <element attribute="valueC">three</element>
</root>
```

And I have this Java class:

```
public class Vals {
    public String valueA;
    public String valueB;
    public String valueC;
}
```

I would like to bind the XML data to Vals by doing something like this:

```
public class Vals {
    @XmlElement(name="element", @XmlAttribute(name="attribute", value_of_attribute="valueA"))
    public String valueA;
    @XmlElement(name="element", @XmlAttribute(name="attribute", value_of_attribute="valueB"))
    public String valueB;
    @XmlElement(name="element", @XmlAttribute(name="attribute", value_of_attribute="valueC"))
    public String valueC;
}
```

Obviously, this is illegal but I hope it demonstrates what I am trying to do: Use annotations to unmarshall data from XML to Java class fields, where the XmlAttribute value determines where to store the XmlElement value.

Answer (score 0):

one approach would be to generate an XSD (xml schema) from your sample XML file (e.g. by using Trang converter), then use the XJC tool to generate initial binding Java classes from the XSD.